# Jasmine unit test not working with simple jquery click

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I'm trying to learn how to unit test with Jasmine. I worked up a very simple example where I am trying to test that a method is called when a jquery click event is triggered. I can't seem to get this to work. Can someone please help? Thanks very much!!

I get the following errors:

```
ReferenceError: Butthead is not defined in http://localhost:4243/spec/buttheadSpec.js (line 11)
```

and

```
spyOn could not find an object to spy upon for responseAlert()
```

here's the code

```
function Butthead(){
}

Butthead.prototype.responseAlert = function(){
   alert('You are a butthead');
}

$(document).ready(function(){

  var butthead = new Butthead();

  $('#myButton').click(function(){

      butthead.responseAlert();
  });
}
```

Here's my unit test

```
// Test Fixture
describe('When clicking myButton', function(){
  var butthead;

  // Set up
  beforeEach(function(){
     butthead = new Butthead(); 
  });


  // Test
  it('should say Hello', function(){

    spyOn(butthead, 'responseAlert');

    $('#myButton').click();

    expect(butthead.responseAlert).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are these in 2 separate files? I know it sounds like a dumb question but it was a mistake I made when I started with Jasmine. You need to separate your "source" and "spec" files.

Remember to reference your Code file with the "Butthead" class declaration first on your spec runner page. You also need to close your script tag reference with  and not just a . I have made this mistake before myself.